# NextJS environment variables not accessible in production build

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have a NextJS application that accesses a database from the API.

When in development, I have a `.env` file that contains the host, port, username, password, and database. After running `npm run dev`, the API functionality works as expected. Even if I run `npm run build` and `npm run start` on my local machine, it works correctly.

The problem comes after I push to Github and have Github build the app and deploy it as a docker container. For some reason, the docker build does not accept my environment variables loaded through an attached `.env` file.

To further elaborate, the environment variables are either on the dev machine or attached to the docker container on the production server. They are mounted to the same place (the root directory of the project: `/my-site/.env`) but the production API does not work.

The environment variables are included in `/lib/db.tsx`:

```js
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

const executeQuery = async (query: string) => {
  try {
    const db = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    });

    const [results] = await db.execute(query, []);
    db.end();

    return results;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};

export default executeQuery;
```

This file is included in the API endpoints as:
`import executeQuery from "../../../../lib/db";`

Again, since it works on the development computer, I think there is an issue is with the building of the docker container.

Here is my included Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts as dependencies
WORKDIR /my-site
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:lts as builder
WORKDIR /my-site
COPY . .
COPY --from=dependencies /my-site/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build

FROM node:lts as runner
WORKDIR /my-site
ENV NODE_ENV production
# If you are using a custom next.config.js file, uncomment this line.
# COPY --from=builder /my-site/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /my-site/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /my-site/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /my-site/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /my-site/package.json ./package.json

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Other things I have attempted:

- Add them as environment variables to the docker container in the docker compose file (under `environment`) and verified that they are accessible inside of the container using `echo $MYSQL_USER`.
- Mounting the `.env` file inside of the `.next` folder
- Mounting the `.env` file inside of the `.next/server` folder

Comment: What version of Next.js are you running? Have you consulted their docs? Older versions required configuring env vars in your next.config.js file (on top of using `.env`).

Comment: Yea! I dug through their docs and it looks like I am doing everything correctly. I am using `Next.js v12.1.4`

Comment: Did you try declaring the environment variables in your `.env` in your Dockerfile first? Like if you have `NEXT_PUBLIC_VAR=value` in your `.env`, you add `ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_VAR value` in your Dockerfile before the build command. If this works, try setting a default value for `ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_VAR default` in the Dockerfile, the values in `.env` should replace them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own issue after hours of trying to figure it out.

My solution was to create a `.env.production` file and commit it to git.

I also adjusted my Dockerfile to include: `COPY --from=builder /my-site/.env.production ./`

I am not a fan of that solution, as it involves pushing secrets to a repo, but it works.

Comment: I am in the same situation, and have not found a solution either. Pushing an authentication secret to a repo seems super risky though. Did you manage to find another solution? I am using docker secrets but that doesn't work either, since can't copy the secret inside .env.production file

Comment: Unfortunately not.. It might be worth making a GitHub ticket regarding this.